# How to executequery while reading data from another sql query in c#?

Tags: c#, sql, while-loop, executequery

I want to `ExecuteQuery()` while reading data from another resultset of `ExecuteQuery`.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("pgwp_teamtypeselect", con);
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

rdr = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

string ehtml = null;
string tipi = null;
int che = 0;

while (rdr.Read())
{
    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("pgwp_goalselect", con);
    cmd2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    rdr2 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

    while (rdr2.Read())
    {
        do something.....
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception or do you want a better way of doing it?

Comment: It seems your inner `while (rdr.Read())` must be `while (rdr2.Read())`

Comment: I am trying to get data with query while in the loop of reading data from another query

Comment: what is the problem are you getting any error or you want some other way to do it ?

Comment: I am new to c# querys to sql , I think I have a wrong logic of code

Comment: I want to know what is the standart way of doing this in C#

Comment: This code is wrong and I want to correct it

Comment: I have corrected rdr2, but thats not the issue here

Comment: Check the answer clear your doubt and dont forget to mark it as accepted if you got infor you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in executing query with in query but I suggest do it making use of using as in below example , So that object get dispose once execution finish

```
using(var command = new SqlCommand("pgwp_teamtypeselect", connection))
{
  command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
  using(var dataReader = command.ExecuteReader())
  {
    while (dataReader.Read()) 
    {
          using(var command1 = new SqlCommand("pgwp_goalselect",  
                       connection))
           {
             command1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

             using(var dataReader2 =command1.ExecuteReader())
             {
             }
           }
    }
}
```

}

You should also add this in your connection string **MultipleActiveResultSets=True"**

```
string connectionString = @"Data Source=GTL-263\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True";
```

you can read this :[Multiple Active Result Sets (MARS - ADO.NET 2.0)](http://dotnetslackers.com/Community/blogs/kaushalparik/archive/2008/06/19/multiple-active-result-sets-mars-ado-net-2-0.aspx) things you are doing is correct.

Comment: where do I write this? - cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

Comment: @IrakliShalamberidze - just before exeucting ..I just want to say you whatever written by you is ok just wrap the thing in using {} you can also visit link and follow the code it is also ok

Comment: @IrakliShalamberidze - weldome check updated answer and dont forget to mark it as accpeted if it works for you